# How and when does mediawiki create and upload files?

Tags: php, mediawiki, cdn, openstack-swift

I'm now busy with my first mediawiki project and I have to connect it to a Swift (CDN) service. I've dropped the regular one (which is specifically for rackspace - we have our own), and built one around our own wrapper - thus far no problem.

Except now mediawiki doesn't create the thumbnails automatically. Maybe something stupid, but I've been cracking my brains and just can find the solution...

This is a part of the config (I can't reveal everything - confidentiality and everything :P):

```
$wgFileBackends[] = array(
    'lockManager'    => 'nullLockManager',
    'class'          => 'SomeSwiftBackend',
    'wikiId'         => 'somewiki',
    'lockManager'    => 'nullLockManager',
    'shardViaHashLevels' => array(
        'remote-public'  => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
        'remote-thumb'   => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
        'local-thumb'    => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
        'remote-archive' => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
        'local-deleted'  => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
        'remote-deleted' => array( 'levels' => 1, 'base' => 36, 'repeat' => false ),
    ),
    'url' => 'http://url-to-swift/v1/AUTH_',
);
```

I probably don't even have that right...

The authentication configuration is passed to our swift backend directly, so you won't find it here...

Comment: Do you get any errors? Look in the server's error logs.

Comment: I get your point, and I've checked, but... It completes the whole cycle - it just doesn't create the thumbnails...

Comment: For now I've reverted it to use the thumbnail script, but that's far from perfect. I'm still looking for the right solution.. _So if anyone has a clue, please share!_ :)

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileBackends) for $wgFileBackends, you need to specify a class and name. I've never used it before but have you tried that?

Also have you seen this extension? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SwiftCloudFiles

Comment: Like I said, I've left out a few details... I'll add some boguss info to prevent these questions again. And SwiftCloudFiles gives too many troubles on our end (and is troublesome if not used on RackSpace), so I ended up writing our own interpretation....